# DataVisualization.Charting chart is not working with ObservableList

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, observable

I'm trying to couple `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` chart with some `ObservableCollection`.

I created class for one data point:

```
public class ChartDataPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double xvalue;

    public double XValue
    {
        get { return xvalue; }
        set {
            if (xvalue != value)
            { 
                xvalue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("XValue");
            }
        }
    }

    private double yvalue;

    public double YValue
    {
        get { return yvalue; }
        set {
            if (yvalue != value)
            {
                yvalue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("YValue");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    private ChartDataPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        this.XValue = x;
        this.YValue = y;
    }

    public static ChartDataPoint CreateNew(double x, double y)
    {
        return new ChartDataPoint(x, y);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created `ObservableCollection<ChartDataPoint>`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListSeries1Data.CollectionChanged += ListSeries1Data_CollectionChanged;
    Chart1.DataContext = ListSeries1Data;
}
```

After my window shows up I'm clicking a button that adds item to my list:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListSeries1Data.Add(ChartDataPoint.CreateNew(i, r.Next(100)));
        i++;
    }
```

And this is part of my XAML with this chart.

```
 <c:Chart Name="Chart1" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <c:LineSeries Name="Series1" 
                      Title="Read value"
                      IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=XValue}"
                      DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=YValue}">
        </c:LineSeries>
</c:Chart>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ItemsSource` for your series. Like this:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="Chart1" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="Series1" 
                  Title="Read value"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=XValue}"
                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=YValue}">
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
 </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```